# Inconsistent spacing around minted environment which varies based on empty lines

Tags: spacing, minted, vertical-spacing

Having an empty line before the minted environment seems to make a big difference in layout. I would prefer to have latex always enforce a consistent layout with only a `\baselineksip` whether I have added an empty line or not. Is this possible?

The reason is that I want consistent spacing around all minted environments in the final output.  Unfortunately I find it tough to be consistent myself.  This is why I write code with the help of a formatter and linters.  So I was wondering if there is a way to enforce the style to be consistent or if there are any linters/formatters available to help me?

Here follows the pdf output:

[image: rendering of latex]

Here follows the latex used to produce the pdf output:

```
\documentclass[
12pt,%
oneside,%
a4paper%
]{memoir}

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\setlength{\partopsep}{-\baselineskip}
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{tango}

\title{Consistent Spacing Around Environments}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{-\baselineskip}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{-\baselineskip}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

If we have a newline before and after the minted section, 
then the rendered spacing above and below is different from when there are no newlines.

Here is the spacing with empty lines above and below.

\begin{minted}{coq}
Inductive regex :=
  | empty_set : regex
  | empty_string : regex
  | symbol : char -> regex
  | concat : regex -> regex -> regex
  | or : regex -> regex -> regex
  .
\end{minted}

Followed by an empty line.
This first spacing is the spacing I want to reproduce below.

Here is a second minted environment without an empty lines.
\begin{minted}{coq}
Inductive regex :=
  | empty_set : regex
  | empty_string : regex
  | symbol : char -> regex
  | concat : regex -> regex -> regex
  | or : regex -> regex -> regex
  .
\end{minted}
Followed by no empty line.
This second spacing is excessive and I want to reduce it to be the same as the first.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!